# Unnecessary output in my text to binary code in Python

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to make a code that will convert text to binary. I know I can make this program easily work by simply using the `encode()` and `decode()` functions, but I wanted to see if I can make it on my own.

This is my program:

```
message=input("Word to translate: ")

remains=""

for value in message:

    number = ord (value)

    while number > 0:

        remain = number % 2

        number = int ( number / 2 )

        remains+=str(remain)

    print(remains[::-1])
```

It works but this is the problem:

```
Word to translate: Hello
1001000
11001011001000
110110011001011001000
1101100110110011001011001000
11011111101100110110011001011001000
```

It seems to create a pyramid for each letter. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De-indent the `print` so it appears outside of the loop.

```
message=input("Word to translate: ")

remains=""

for value in message:

    number = ord (value)

    while number > 0:

        remain = number % 2

        number = int ( number / 2 )

        remains+=str(remain)

print(remains[::-1])
```